# HTML Canvas - Create a Highlighter Effect

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am creating a two layer canvas. The bottom layer is a screenshot. The top layer is the drawing surface.  I figured out a basic pen. I want to create a highlighter effect - meaning a larger line with a set opacity .5 or less.  The problem I am having is that when I draw over the same area more than once the colors paint on top of each other.  Eventually, the highlight will turn solid and block out the lower layer. I want to highlight evenly with the original color and be able to draw over existing highlights without the colors adding up.

I have been messing around with globalCompositeOperation but cannot get the desired results with the settings I have tried.  Below i am trying `color` and using a globalAlpha setting. I have also tried using `rgba` colors. I also tried just using one layer, but I wanted to be able to clear doodles and erase easily so I went with two.  Some of my source code is in the picture, but I'm not sure how helpful code is for my question.  I can provide more if needed. Thanks.

[image]

EDIT: After using `multiply` as the `globalCompositionOperation` the color `#FF0` aka yellow works great, among other colors.  Some colors still have the original build-to-black effect, like the blue I use in the bottom picture. As a side note, these pictures are not to share my code, they are to show the highlighter effect.  As a side note, this an Electron app so it is using Chromium ~ 61 at this time.

[image]

Comment: post your code as text and not as image

Comment: @LelioFaieta how is he suppose to illustrate the yellow highlights with just text?

Comment: thanks @epistemex. hopefully they just misunderstood my original post...but yah I am showing the problem.  I did mention that this isnt really a code problem, either someone knows how to do this effect or they dont.

Comment: By adding the picture side by side with the code? As everyone here usually does

Comment: No idea why all these people would downvote this, it's a perfectly good question.  I'm trying to accomplish the same thing, but unfortunately using Multiply isn't working for me, it looks slightly better than default but it still gets darker as you drag the mouse over the same spot multiple times.  I'm creating a way for students to annotate online learning worksheets, and highlighting text is a feature I need, but the text should always show through the highlight.  Any suggestions?  Did the behavior of Multiply change?

Comment: I think my problem is probably because I'm still using moveTo/lineTo/stroke methods to draw, whereas this example is using fillRect.  I don't think using multiply setting works when drawing with stroke - the lines are still additive.  I can see though how using fillRect with multiply might result in the lines not stacking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The normal way to create a highlighter effect is to use the blending mode "multiply".

This will be like on real paper (subtractive light, not technically but in appearance) so drawing on a dark background will produce an almost invisible highlighter effect.

Note that not all browsers support blending modes (this includes <= IE11).

```js
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
ctx.font = "40px sans-serif";
ctx.fillText("HIGHLIGHT ME", 5, 84);        // replace with bg image
ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0";
c.onmousemove = e => ctx.fillRect(e.clientX-10, e.clientY-10, 20,20);
```

```css
html, body {margin:0}
#c {border:1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

On dark background:

```js
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#333";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
ctx.font = "40px sans-serif";
ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
ctx.fillText("HIGHLIGHT ME", 5, 84);        // replace with bg image
ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0";
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
c.onmousemove = e => ctx.fillRect(e.clientX-10, e.clientY-10, 20,20);
```

```css
html, body {margin:0}
#c {border:1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

Comment: Good call got things working like I wanted.  I am going to update my original post with another picture with what I see as weird behavior.  The effect works great for yellow or `#FF0`, some other colors end up black after multiple strokes, while others appear black to begin with.  I would have to look into the math that happens behind the scenes to understand what is happening.  But thanks again - yellow is the perfect color for this.  I also thought about implementing some kind of array that stores the highlighted pixels, and checks the array to prevent redrawing...